# Issues adding a class to jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to add an additional class to my jQuery dialog with the `dialogClass` property. Here's the javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#toogleMAmaximized" ).dialog({
            title: 'Missions and Achivments',
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: 'noPadding',
            buttons: {
                    Cancel: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
            },
            close: function() {
                    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            }

    })
    $( "#toogleMAminimized" ).click(function() {
            $( "#toogleMAmaximized" ).dialog( "open" );
            $( "#toogleMAmaximized" ).dialog({dialogClass:'noPadding'});
    });
})

<div id="toogleMAminimized" style="" class="noPadding">
<div class="" style="cursor: pointer;position: absolute;right: 0;top: 45px;"><img src ="images/MAminimized.png" alt="missions and achivments"/></div>
</div>
```

Just in case you need it, my html code

```
<div id="toogleMAmaximized" >
<div id="missions">
    <div id="mission1" missiontitle="A new home!" missionpoint="1" missionicon="images/missions/icon/anewhome-icon.png" missionimage="images/missions/anewhome.png" made="f" class="mission notDone">  </div>
</div>
<div id="achivments">
    <div id="achivment1" achivmenttitle="Lucha sin cuartel!" achivmentpoint="10" achivmenticon="images/achivments/icon/1.png" achivmentimage="images/achivments/icon/luchasincuartel-plata-ico.png" made="t" class="achivment done">  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I've tried to add the class in many ways, I've tried all possible combinations but keep getting the same result: no `noPadding` class

Comment: `dialogClass` [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/QHJKm/). Your code [also works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/QHJKm/1/).

Comment: what version of `jQuery UI`? i'm using `jQuery UI 1.8.16`. Just saw it used 1.8.18 let me check that. Ty!

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/QHJKm/3/) with 1.8.16 too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `noPadding` class is being added successfully to the dialog. I have confirmed this by placing your markup and scripts within a fiddle, and loading jQuery UI 1.8.16 (the version you were testing with). This test is available online at http://jsfiddle.net/QHJKm/3/.

I suspect the confusion here is with the expected effect `noPadding` is going to have on the dialog itself. It could be that you interpreted its lack of effect as an indication it wasn't added to begin with. As you'll note in my example, I've got with a rather bold style, a red background. This quickly confirms that the class is indeed being added to the dialog.

Comment: im very confused in here, how can i further debug this? the only way i get the `noPadding` class is hardcording it in the `toogleMAmaximized` div it self. Could i have a broken 1.8.16? i'm downloading a new version now.

Comment: Oh!, now i understand what you are saying! it's not added to `toogleMAmaximized` as i would expect but to the prior div element created! (the one with rol=dialog property to anyone not familiar with it either). Ok, so the only one thing left to do is add the class to the real div, just after the dialog("open"), thank you!