# Selecting an element in JQuery by its style attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three divs' all have same class. The difference is their styles. In my case a want to select only the third one using the JQuery.

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-divProfile" style="display: none; z-index: 1000; outline: 0px;"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-divProfile">Edit Profile</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div><div id="divProfile" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"></div></div>

<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-divChangePassword" style="display: none; z-index: 1000; outline: 0px;"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-divChangePassword">Change Password</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div><div id="divChangePassword" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"></div></div>

<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-4" style="display: block; z-index: 1052; outline: 0px; height: auto; width: 900px; top: 154.5px; left: 226.5px; opacity: 0.0784;"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-4">&nbsp;</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div><div class="dialog ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0" style="width: auto; min-height: 83.8400001525879px; height: auto;">
```

I am doing like this

```
$('.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable')
```

but it give me the all three divs'.I only want the third one which has z-index=1052. How can I select that one. Is there a way in JQuery to select element by its attribute.

Comment: It depends on what makes the third div diffreent form other

Comment: Why not simply add an extra class to the third `div` and reference that?

Comment: @Andy that's exactly the right approach.  Using DOM position and/or z-index will be very brittle.

Comment: You can add classes for z-index e.g. top-element, bottom-element.

Comment: @ozil you're wasting loads of people's time by failing to answer the fundamental question you've been asked - _what makes this particular div special_ ?

Comment: your html should be like this not which you have pasted http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes the markup you're seeing above is what actually appears in the DOM once jQuery has created a dialog wrapper around the coder-supplied div.

Comment: so he can add class for using for that dialog http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-dialogClass

Comment: Oh, and it appears incomplete - it's missing the content element and the closing tags of the third dialog, the very one he's interested in!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787865/issues-adding-a-class-to-jquery-ui-dialog

Comment: every dialog has different id `divProfile` `divChangePassword` i cant see the third one because its incomplete

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes it looks like the third dialog is partly there, with a class of just `dialog`, but no ID.  jQuery UI itself doesn't add that class, so the OP must have.

Comment: yes the solution would be he can add a class for the dialog with higher `z-index` because `jquery ui Dialog` is not giving  `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) for this:

```
$('.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable:eq(2)')
```

Comment: What you did previously with getting the `z-index` value with `.css()` and `parseInt()` seemed exactly what the author was looking for. I'm not sure why you edited that out.

Comment: @silvenon because `$(this).css('z-index')` returns `auto`, `auto`, `0` for these elements.

Comment: In jQuery-UI 1.10.x, DOM position will be inconsistent as soon as you click on any other dialog - that version of jQuery UI always put the "topmost" stacked dialog last in the DOM, but other major versions use the z-Index.

Comment: One line of code like this
$('.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable').attr('z-i‌​ndex', '1052')

Comment: My main concern is can I select an element by its attribute in JQuery.

Comment: @ozil Yes, you can select by element's attribute (not by CSS value). For example, you can select by `aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-4"` (as I see it's unique in your code).

Comment: @Regent I did like this
$('.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable').attr('aria-labelledby', 'ui-dialog-title-4')
But still all three div's

Comment: @ozil I mean you can use `$('.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-4"]')` or maybe short `$('[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-4"]')`

Comment: @ozil yes, you can select an element by attribute.  However you have to pick an attribute that it actually makes sense to select on, i.e. one that's fixed.  The best one is one you added yourself, and for performance reasons it's better that this be a class (or ID) rather than a true HTML attribute.

Comment: @Regent $('[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-4"]') still selects all three div's

Comment: @ozil read my answer, and then think again, please.  You _must_ find some other way of tagging the dialog, preferably at creation time.  Think about what makes this particular dialog the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to select dialogs either by DOM position or by z-index - the latter will vary frequently as dialogs are moved or restacked, and the way both values behave varies depending on the jQuery UI version (see below)

Find some other way of tagging the dialog you're interested in when you create it (e.g. add a specific ID or unique class), and then select on that.

For example, looking at the (incomplete) HTML that you've supplied, I can see that the first two content divs have IDs `#divProfile` and `#divChangePassword`.  The third content div has no ID but does appear to have an extra class of `dialog`.

```
$('.dialog').closest('.ui-dialog')
```

or add an ID and use:

```
$('#divWotIWant').closest('.ui-dialog')
```

---

Initially, jQuery UI dialogs used z-index for stacking.  In jQuery UI 1.10.x they changed to using constant (auto?) z-index and then relying on DOM order to control stacking, since when multiple elements with the same z-index overlap it's always the last one in DOM order that appears topmost.

However the devs found that moving a dialog out of the DOM and reinserting it caused issues with things like Flash player if they were embedded in a dialog (causing the player to reset any time you clicked on a dialog) so they reverted back to using z-indexes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this if you know which element to select:

```
$('[aria-labelledby=ui-dialog-title-4]')
```

Comment: $('[aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-4"]') still selects all three div's

Comment: @ozil i doubt, it will select all the divs which has aria-labelledby set to 'ui-dialog-title-4'. So considering above html code, there is only one div labelled with 'ui-dialog-title-4' attribute. Please check again at ur end. The code line is working fine at my end.

Comment: @ozil I again checked with more filters - '$('.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content[aria-labelledby=ui-dialog-title-4]').length'. And this too worked fine at my end returning only one element.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use **nth-child**

```
$('.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable:nth-child(3)')
```

Comment: what is a problem with nth-child..?

Answer (score -1):

this will give you desired task. In alert you are getting the reference of third element which z-index 1052.

```
$('.ui-dialog.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-draggable').each(function() {
    if($(this).css("z-index")=="1052"){
        alert($(this).html());
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, no, it will not: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn8xvj2o/1/). I have already made this mistake. `z-index` is not even close to be `1052` in reality.

Comment: @Regent exactly as I warned about in my answer.  You _cannot_ rely on the zIndex being any specific value.

Comment: please add document ready.. its working I have tried. create a document and check. don't downvote without knowing

Comment: @Alinatak replace if conditon with $(this).attr("attr name").contains("required text")

Comment: @AkashSarawagi there is "domready" in left part of fiddle. `$(this).css("z-index")` simply returns `auto`, `auto` and `0` for these three `<div>`s for me. So, as it was already said many times, you can't rely on `.css("z-index")`

Answer (score -1):

Try this-
It is selecting specific div based on the z-index.

http://jsfiddle.net/6yzbwm6h/

```
$("* [style*='z-index: 1052']").filter(function () { alert($(this).html()) });
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It works for `z-index: 1052` well, yes. The only problem is that it won't work for `z-index:1052` but will work for `z-index: 10520`

Comment: It is not a general solution, but it is solving the users problem and can be used here.