# Jquery UI dialog custom animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

who can help to implement custom css animation to JQuery UI dialog?

For me custom animation is working only when dialog opens, if I close dialog, I can't make animation to appear again in reversed mode.

I tested with GETUIKIT animations:
[UIkit project link](https://getuikit.com/docs/animation#usage)
Below is my code example which works when dialog opens, but custom animation doesn't work when closing dialog.

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog({
dialogClass: "uk-animation-slide-top-medium",
autoOpen: false,
resizable: false,
})
```

Css class which reverts same animation is: uk-animation-slide-top-medium uk-animation-reverse. I tried to add animation-reverse class using beforeClose event, but no luck.

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not use UIKIT modal (https://getuikit.com/docs/modal#usage) instead of implementing a mix with Jquery UI Dialog

Comment: Yes, UIKIT is quite limited, I will just use animations. But at first I need to know how to use them with JQueryUI dialog.

Comment: read this issue and its solutions on understanding on jquery UI custom class works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787865/issues-adding-a-class-to-jquery-ui-dialog

Comment: Please debug your code and see what is the class that gets added in developer console of your chrome browser

Comment: Class is added as it should, but it doesn't affect Dialog close procedure. No errors, just animation doesn't work on close.

Comment: Seems no one knows how to find solution?

Comment: can you create a fiddle of your existing code with uikit ?